# VGA port only works when using snip tool?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, vga, lenovo-laptop

My VGA port on my Lenovo Y410p laptop stopped working last week.

I have ruled out the cable, monitor, and I think windows from being the issue. The screen is detected by the laptop and the operating system, but nothing displays. Unless I open the snip tool, and go into snip mode. Then I get a very weak display on the screen that is otherwise not showing anything.

I'm thinking its a power issue with the VGA port, but I thought it would be worth checking here in case someone has seen that before.

Comment: What happens if you set the secondary monitor as the primary display?

Comment: No Change sadly. I've determined that its the laptop vga plug.

Comment: @Brett try running a live operating system from a cd or usb drive. download ubuntu  live disk and try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you already tried what I'm going to suggest you: even if they might seem obvious things to check, sometimes simple things get overlooked, so I'm writing them anyway.. in case, just skip over :-)

*(and from what you say, you have already done the first two)*

- Try moving the connectors both on monitor and on computer side, even removing and plugging them again: they sometimes get oxidated and weaken the signal..
- If you have another another computer, 
  try your monitor on that output and see if it works
- If you have another monitor, 
  try connecting it to your laptop and see what you get.
- Check your monitor light and contrast knobs.

Since VGA has an analogic signal, a weak output could mean that a signal is arriving to the screen, but the screen hardly "hears" it..

- Try checking the working frequency that is set to the vga output from the monitor configuration panel: if it is too high, either your monitor will not sync, or it will sync but looking darker than usual (this usually applies to CRT monitors.. but I don't know which kind of monitor you're working with..)
- There is also the possibility of misconfigured color or gamma settings from the video card settings..

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments. After working through these, its evident that its the VGA plug on the laptop.